# Spring authorization

Tags: java, spring, jsp, authorization, spring-security

I have some problems with authorization. So, my app has login.jsp page. web.xml file has this lines:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I'm using Spring Security for users authorizing. So, when my app starts (something like http://localhost:8080/myApp), it goes to login.jsp page. When user successfully authorize, app send them to welcome.jsp page. But when I write in address bar path to my app (when I successfully authorized), it again send me to login page. How to avoid this problem and redirect authorized users to some page (e.g. welcome.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` means the webapp will always start on this page, regardless of authorized state.

The typical authorization sequence in a app is:

1. Serve index.html (or .jsp), the welcome page.
2. User tries to access a protected resource, say /protected.jsp
3. Server answers 401 Authorization Required with a redirect to /login.jsp
4. User submits login for.
5. Server sets session cookies indicating authorized state and redirects back to /protected.jsp
6. User views /protected.jsp

If you want the user to start on the login page, you are probably best off setting up the above flow, and then do an automatic redirect on your welcome page `index.html` to /protected.jsp.